# How do I combine two texture maps into one model?

Tags: modeling, texturing, objects

I have two sides of a roman coin modelled using agisoft photoscan, joined together using blender (photoscan failed to model the whole coin so I thought I might be able to use blender to do that). I can see my coin with both textures on in texture paint mode but when I export the model I can't find the texture map? Is there a way to combine two texture maps into one and have it exported together with the model? Ultimately, I just want to upload the full coin into sketchfab for viewing.

Would anyone be able to help? I do not have a lot of experience using Blender. Thank you in advance! :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: What format are you exporting the model in? There are lots of ways to combine texture maps, but it depends on the default wrapping (wrapping written by the scanner). Could you add an image to help clarify? Blender supports exporting as a .ply with vertex colours, so you have everything in one file; just bake the texture to the vertex colours.

Comment: https://skfb.ly/NOTK

the exported model looks like this and I can't find the texture file anywhere?

I have tried .obj and .fbx but neither seemed to have textures on them.

Answer (score 1):

When exporting, textures aren't necessarily saved in the same directory as the model. To find out where the texture is saved for an .obj, open the .mtl file:

[image: .mtl file]

If you don't see a .mtl file in the same directory as the .obj, it may not have been written. To ensure an .mtl is written, select "Write Materils" in the file window when exporting.

[image]

If you'd like the textures and model together in one file, bake the textures to the vertex colours and export as .ply:

[image]
[image]